# Invalidate user in Identity Core when roles/account changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

First - I'm still learning Identity Core (and .NET core in general). I'm using Google Authentication (internal only project). I tested an account and deleted it. I noticed even after deleting it from the database I can still browse around in secured parts of the page.

Is there a way to automatically log the user out if the account is no longer valid?

Comment: I don't know if it works for external authentication but it is worth trying setting the validation interval
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options => options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

Comment: Have you tried `_signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync` method which take the user as parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't try the RefreshSignInAsync but @Stilgar's method worked.

Comment: I guess I'll add it as an answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the validation interval is supposed to do

```
Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options => options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

There is also a callback OnRefreshingPrincipal you can use to plug custom logic

Comment: What if that doesn't work? I have the ValidationInterval set to 1 minute in my project and have implemented OnRefreshingPrincipal and the cookie is never refreshed and the code in OnRefreshingPrincipal is never executed. In my case I just want to change the user's role and have their claims get updated or force them to login again.

Comment: Update: I figured out why OnRefreshingPrincipal is never called and I'll mention it here in case anyone else runs into this. It's because I implemented a custom cookie event handler by setting services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.Eventtype = typeof(CustomCookieEvents); }). Apparently if you handle those with a cusotm class then the default security stamp validation never happens. That was not obvious to me and the documentation about it seems to be lacking or maybe I just missed it.

Comment: @SteveHiner Thank you for writing this comment, I faced a similar situation. How did you find out that was the issue? Is there any documentation around for this?

Comment: @DotnetShadow I never did find any documentation about it. I think I eventually just thrashed enough trying to solve the problem that I was trying all kinds of things and removed my custom cookie handler. Also quite possible that I stripped the startup code to bare bones then started building it back up again to find out when it would fail.